# SQL Server User table permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions

What is the SQL Server script to create a user and set table permissions to that user?

1. Create user using script
2. Set table permissions to that user using script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) [Creating a server login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx):

```
CREATE LOGIN AbolrousHazem 
    WITH PASSWORD = '340$Uuxwp7Mcxo7Khy';
```

2) [Creating a corresponding database user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
CREATE USER AbolrousHazem FOR LOGIN AbolrousHazem;
```

3) [Granting to select from a table:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx)

```
GRANT SELECT ON TableName TO AbolrousHazem
```

Follow the provided links to get more information.